# Is it possible to access javascript return value outside of function?

Tags: javascript

```
milkmachine = function(argument){
    var r=1, k=2;
    //.....
    return r;
}
milkmachine(); //returns r, good
milkmachine.set_return_to_another_variable('k');
milkmachine(); //this should return k
```

Comment: Could you try to compose a theoretical example? "return something somewhere else in the code" doesn't make sense to me -- the function returns wherever it was called. You could store the return value and use it later, or you could trigger an event listener elsewhere in the code, maybe. But I can't say for sure what you need because I don't fully understand what you want.

Comment: This just looks like a fundamental misunderstanding about how functions work.  A function with a `return` statement *will* return a value.  You access that value later by storing it into a variable so that you can refer to it later.

Comment: right but can you change what the function will return outside of the function?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull So you're asking: is it possible to alter the code of the function, after it's been defined, to make it return whatever is in the internal variable `k` instead of what's the internal variable `r` as it was defined to return?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I am also curious if this can be done inside the function . . . but that sounds more complicated.

Comment: I think the short answer to this question is "No".

Comment: People who put the question on hold, please provide some suggestions on how I can clarify.

Comment: Also, is the return not somehow a property of the function object?

Comment: There are properties, and then there are properties. The fact that a function returns a value and the type of that return value are properties -- aspects -- of a function that are fixed when it is declared; this is in contrast with an object's "properties", which are values that the object contains that can (sometimes) be modified (i.e. assigned a different value). _What_ a function returns is not the latter type of property, it is inherent in the function. To be able to change it would be to change the code of the function after it was created.

Comment: If the function is inside another function that traps the return value via a closure function, then yes, you can pretty much do what you want. But even if this question were fresh, it's not specific enough to be certain that would work in context.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer, as Greg Hewgill commented, is: no (to the best of my knowledge). There are a few shoddy ways you could get that behavior as well as a few recommended ways:

**Shoddy Way #1:**

One way is to have two versions of the function: one that returns `r`, the other that returns `k`. This is not recommended because it is duplicating the same code, just returning something different.

**Shoddy Way #2:**

Another option would be to add another parameter to the function which would specify the variable you want to be returned:

```
milkmachine = function(argument, retWhat){
    var r;
    var k;

    //do something with arguments and variables

    if (retWhat == "k")
        return k;
    else
        return r;
}
```

This is also bad since you're using one function to do multiple things and a function should only do *one thing*; also, it gives external code more info about the inner workings of the function than is good. (There are probably other, better reasons this is bad, but I can't think of any at the moment.)

**Recommended Way #1:**

Instead of returning just one value, you could return both values wrapped in a container object:

```
milkmachine = function(argument){
    var r;
    var k;

    //do something with arguments and variables

    return new MilkMachineRetrunValue(r, k);
}

var retval = milkmachine("some arg");
// access retval.r here
// access retval.k here

// or you could directly access the variable
// that you wanted within the return wrapper
// after the call like so:
// milkmachine("some arg").k
```

**Recommended Way #2**

Use an object:

```
function MilkMachine() {
    this.r;
    this.k;
}

MilkMachine.prototype.run = function(argument) {

    //do something with arguments and variables
}

var mm = new MilkMachine();
mm.run("some arg");
// access mm.r here
// access mm.k here
```

Comment: Recommended Way #1 simplified:  `return {'r': r, 'k': k}`